# Iterating JS array of objects and returning matched objects as well removing it from the original array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a better way in iterating over a array of objects in Javascript where i also want to do two more functionalities

1. Removing the matched element from the original array
2. As well returning it.

For Example,

```
  var originalArray = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}];

  var matchedArray = originalArray.filter(function(n, i, arr) {
      return (n.id == 1 || n.id == 2 || n.id == 5) && arr.splice(i, 1)
  });
```

The output im looking for

> original array as :  [{id:3},{id:4}]
>
> matched array as  :  [{id:1},{id:2},{id:5}]

Comment: do you need to keep the reference of `originalArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic function `partition`: given an array and a predicate (=boolean) function, it splits the array into "falsy" and "truthy" parts:

```js
function partition (ary, predicate) {
    var rs = [[], []];
    ary.forEach(function(x) {
        rs[predicate(x) ? 1 : 0].push(x);
    });
    return rs;
};
   
///

var originalArray = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}];

var parts = partition(originalArray, function(n) {
   return n.id == 1 || n.id == 2 || n.id == 5
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(parts[0]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(parts[1]))
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than the others. However, I'd consider using a `for..of` loop instead of `forEach`.

Comment: @AaditMShah: thanks, I'm trying to stay on ES5 this time.

Comment: @AaditMShah: I only use `reduce` when it's a single expression, stuff like "add this to that; return that" makes me sick ;)

Comment: That's true. Only if we had a native JS method that would behave like `push` and `concat`. Something like `(xs, x) => (xs.push(x), xs)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are removed an element then on the next iteration the actual element index and the index in the callback would be different and this result unexpected output.

Use a while loop to iterate in reverse order and generate the new array and remove the value from the main array. Although you can avoid the multiple conditions by using an array and checking value present in the array using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method(for older browser support use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method).

```
var matchedArray = [],
  i = originalArray.length;

while (i--) {
  if ([1, 2, 5].includes(originalArray[i].id)) 
    matchedArray.push(originalArray.splice(i, 1)[0])
}
```

```js
var originalArray = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 4
}, {
  id: 5
}];

var matchedArray = [],
  i = originalArray.length;

while (i--) {
  if ([1, 2, 5].includes(originalArray[i].id)) 
    matchedArray.push(originalArray.splice(i, 1)[0])
}

console.log(matchedArray);
console.log(originalArray);
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** An alternate method using [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) method with the same logic.

```
var matchedArray = originalArray.reduceRight(function(arr, o, i, orig) {
  if ([1, 2, 5].includes(o.id))
    arr.push(orig.splice(i, 1)[0])
  return arr;
}, [])
```

```js
var originalArray = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 4
}, {
  id: 5
}];

var matchedArray = originalArray.reduceRight(function(arr, o, i, orig) {
  if ([1, 2, 5].includes(o.id))
    arr.push(orig.splice(i, 1)[0])
  return arr;
}, [])

console.log(matchedArray);
console.log(originalArray);
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** Although you can do it with the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method with an additional variable holds the count of removed elements which helps to calculate the new index on updated array.

```
var c = 0;

var matchedArray = originalArray.filter(function(n, i, arr) {
  return [1, 2, 5].includes(n.id) && arr.splice(i - c--, 1)
});
```

```js
var originalArray = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 4
}, {
  id: 5
}];

var c = 0;

var matchedArray = originalArray.filter(function(n, i, arr) {
  return [1, 2, 5].includes(n.id) && arr.splice(i - c--, 1)
});

console.log(matchedArray);
console.log(originalArray);
```

Comment: Love this solution. It does exactly what the OP asks for. Also, thank you for introducing me to `includes`.

Comment: @AaditMShah : glad to help :) ... for old browser use `Array#indexOf` method `.indexOf(originalArray[i].id) > -1`

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions. You can adjust the `ids` array and specify which id's you want to filter.

```js
var originalArray = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}];
var ids = [1,2,5];

var filtered = [];
var notFiltered = [];

filtered = originalArray.filter(v => ids.some(c => c == v.id));
notFiltered = originalArray.filter(v => filtered.every(c => c.id != v.id));

console.log(filtered);
console.log(notFiltered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.remove function from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove) which solves this elegantly.

```js
let originalArray = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}];

const matchedArray = _.remove(originalArray, function(n) {
  return (n.id == 1 || n.id == 2 || n.id == 5);
});

console.log(originalArray);
console.log(matchedArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using underscoreJs for example:

```
var originalArray = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}];
var matchedArray = _.filter(originalArray,function(n){return (n.id == 1 || n.id == 2 || n.id == 5);});
originalArray = _.difference(originalArray,matchedArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i would like perform this operation with plain javascript instead of using dependency libraries like Underscore JS